# What type of solder to use with unregulated 25W soldering iron?

Tags: soldering, repair, soldering-iron-station

I have a general purpose unregulated 25W soldering iron (soldering pencil.)

What type of solder is suitable for this (melting point degrees, composition?)

Mainly for simple repair work (solder wires, terminal connector headers, through-hole mounting components.)

Answer (score 3):

Any common leaded solder (60/40 or 63/37) with rosin flux core will do. Iron wattage does not dictate solder type. Wattage mainly dictates work piece size. Use as big a chisel tip as you can possibly get away with. I recommend 2.4mm for what you described, maybe even 4mm. Conical tips are terrible...stay away from them.

Comment: Lead-free solder does have a higher melt temperature requiring expensive temp controlled solder stations.

Comment: In reality most cheap irons will melt lead free, the problem is that they get *too host* -  lead free is much more damaged by overtemperature.  Trying to get a joint done while visiting a relative with a typical "fire starter" and on hand lead free solder I found I actually had to unplug it and solder as it *cooled*.